# Установить последнюю версию php imagick на ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, php7, imagick

Помогите пожалуйста установить последнюю версию php imagick на ubuntu 16.04, php 7.0
Командой "sudo apt-get install php-imagick" выдает "Уже установлен пакет php-imagick самой новой версии (3.4.0~rc6-1ubuntu3)". Хотя на сайте https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick есть версия 3.4.4.
Можно ли установить последнюю версию или хотя бы не такую старую, как текущая? Спасибо!

Comment: Через композер?

Answer (score 1):

Установка imagick для php происходит через pecl. Должны быть установлены пакеты:

imagemagick libmagickwand-dev php7.0-dev pkg-config

Сама установка

> sudo pecl install imagick